# C# Excel DateTime Export

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I need to export some data to an Excel sheet. The data builds up from data time values and readings.
The problem of mine that when I export the date time values they change their format to US dates instead of UK.

I tried to sort it by adding the format to the range where the date time values are, now it even gets funnier. I noticed that till month 9 it is handling the date time values right in UK format but after that it changes to US one.

After opening the excel file the format what I insert on cells by the application is applied only on the US formats.

Please see my code, it might give help to solve my problem:

```
        // Get dimensions of the 2-d array
        int rowCount = data2.GetLength(0);
        int columnCount = data2.GetLength(1);
        // Get an Excel Range of the same dimensions
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        range = range.get_Resize(rowCount, columnCount);
        // Assign the 2-d array to the Excel Range
        range.set_Value(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, data2);

        // Reset the range
        range = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        range = range.get_Resize(rowCount, 1);
        // Set the format type of the range
        range.NumberFormat = "DD/MMM/YYYY hh:mm:ss";
```

**EDIT SOLUTION**
With adrianm help here's the solution code:

I left the previously included code the same, but I changed the code which is creating the data2 object array (object[,] data2)

```
        //create the empty array
        var result = new object[data.Count, data[0].Count];
        //insert all of the values in it
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < data[i].Count; j++)
            {
                if (j < data[i].Count)
                    result[i, j] = data[i][j];
                else
                    result[i, j] = " ";
            }
        }

        //change the date time values to doubles which are 
        //in the first column after the first entry
        for (int i = 1; i < data.Count; i++)
        {
            result[i, 0] = (Convert.ToDateTime(result[i, 0])).ToOADate();
        }

            return result;
```

Comment: dates in excel are just numbers. Change the dates in your array to the excel number with `DateTime.ToOADate()`

Comment: @adrianm my array is from objects, as it contains the column titles etc as well. Anyway I guess I will try to split up the data from different arrays, will see what it does then

Comment: Can't you just convert the dates to numbers inside the array in a loop like `data2[x, y] = data2[x, y].ToOADate()`?

Comment: @adrianm thanks, it works perfectly:) If you post a solution I will accept it. Thank you again

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer and accept your own answer! This is the recommended way, rather than editing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With adrianm help here's the solution code:

I left the previously included code the same, but I changed the code which is creating the data2 object array (object[,] data2)

```
    //create the empty array
    var result = new object[data.Count, data[0].Count];
    //insert all of the values in it
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i].Count; j++)
        {
            if (j < data[i].Count)
                result[i, j] = data[i][j];
            else
                result[i, j] = " ";
        }
    }

    //change the date time values to doubles which are 
    //in the first column after the first entry
    for (int i = 1; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        result[i, 0] = (Convert.ToDateTime(result[i, 0])).ToOADate();
    }

        return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to format entire column as a date column like this

range.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY";

Hope this will work

Comment: try to use hh:mm:ss AM/PM